# Hide a static cell of Tableview in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I've an application that works with a static cells table view. In some cases in need to hide a few cells and when needed show them again. How can i do this ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift. Either you can hide and show static cells or you can't. Language is irrelevant. Your question is about Cocoa (UIKit), not about a language.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to ask a yes/no question? Suppose the answer is Yes. Is that really _all_ you want to know? It's all you've asked...

Comment: He asked how to do this, so, imho, this question about Swift is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do what you wanna do I work with numberOfRowsInSection tableview's method using a bool variabile

```
if section == 3 {
    if !hideTableSection! { return 1 } else { return 2 }
}
```

Every time I need to hide some cell I change the bool variable then I reload my table.

It can manage only the latest rows of every section but I didn't find nothing better...

Comment: this code, just hides it's content. I want to hide it's place too.

Comment: Edited previous reply